Bluescreen error in windows 7 WimFsf.sys
BSOD Error is showing while strting the laptop
PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA
***STOP: 0X00000050
*** wimFsf.sys Address FFFFF88001BAF735 base at FFFFF88001BAD000, DateStamp
4a5bc362

On clicking on any option in advanced boot option it takes me back to the blue screen
How to debug??

If you try and boot into Safe Mode, are you able to boot into Windows?

I tried that but blue screen appears again :(

So have you ran the appropriate DISM and SFC commands within WinRE to attempt to repair the system corruption?  I assume if the system crashes due to wimFsf.sys the file is corrupt and required to boot

I m not able to boot into windows

And tried all the advanced boot options

But blue screen error occurs

You don't have to boot into Windows, you need to boot into WinRE, which should be possible if your using a standard Windows installation and the recovery partition is properly configured.  It sounds like your system drive is failing you have corrupt system files, my suggestion, reinstall on Windows on a new storage device.

@NakulJodha: The first google search gave me the following information: How To Fix Wimfsf.sys BSOD Error (Bluescreen). I would advise to try check the RAM. If the memory modules are not soldered, try to remove them and clean the contacts. If there are several modules in your laptop, try to remove and start the system with each of them separately. This requires some qualification, otherwise you need go to a service center...
